# PySide / wait or sleep

Tags: pyside

i´m new to python and pyside. I´ll try to run the following code with success. But now i want the programm to wait after showing up the window for a defined time where the user can´t use it and then upgrade the statusbar. i´ll tried sleep() but have no idea where it had to be placed the correct way in the code. Thanks for help.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
ZetCode PySide tutorial 

This program creates a statusbar.

author: Jan Bodnar
website: zetcode.com 
last edited: August 2011
"""

import sys, time
from PySide import QtGui

class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):               

    exitAction = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('exit.png'), '&Exit', self)
    exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
    exitAction.setStatusTip('Exit application')
    exitAction.triggered.connect(self.close)        

    self.statusBar().showMessage('no connection')

    menubar = self.menuBar()
    fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
    fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)

    self.setGeometry(100, 100, 400,300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Main')    
        self.show() 

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Main()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `sleep`. Sleep will only block the active event loop, the user can still click anywhere in the GUI and the events will be delivered delayed after `sleep` has returned.

If you want to disable user interaction, then disable the widget (and use a timer to reenable it). A simple example in your case could look like this:

```
...
def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Main()
    ex.setEnabled(False)
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(4000, lambda: es.setEnabled(True))
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
...
```